# AWS Lambda best practices for Real Time Tracking

Tags: amazon-web-services

We currently run an AWS Lambda function that primarily simply redirects the user to a different URL. The function is invoked via API-Gateway.

For tracking purposes, we would like to create a widget on our dashboard that provides real-time insights into how many redirects are performed each second. **The creation of the widget itself is not the problem.**

My main question currently is which AWS Services is best suited for telling our other services that an invocation took place. We plan to register the invocation in our database.

Some additional things:

- low latency (< 5 seconds) in order to be real-time data
- nearly no increased time wait for the user. We aim to redirect the user as fast as possible

Many thanks in advance!

Best Regards
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that your goal is to simply persist the information that an invocation happened somewhere with minimal impact on the response time of the Lambda.

For that purpose I'd probably use an SQS standard queue and just send a message to the queue that the invocation happened.
You can then have an asynchronous process (Lambda, Docker, EC2) process the messages from the queue and update your Dashboard.

Depending on the scalability requirements looking into Kinesis Data Analytics might also be worth it.
It's a fully managed streaming data solution and the analytics part allows you to do sliding window analyses using SQL on data in the Stream.
In that case you'd write the info that something happened to the stream, which also has a low latency.

Comment: Thank you Maurice for your response.

Does SQS scale any "worse" than Kinesis Data Analytics?
From my understanding, isn't it is also a fully managed microservice, or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: SQS scaling is no issue. The services are different in what they do - using SQS you have to manage scaling of the consumer part - this is something that Kinesis Data Analytics has partially built-in.